# How to save tree Uri in SQLiftDatabase in android

Tags: android, uri

I get a tree Uri from this code:

```
create_data_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);


            //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            //intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        }
    });
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

    folder_uri=data.getData();
    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(folder_uri,takeFlags);

}
```

Then I save the tree Uri to a SQLDatabase as a String:

```
folder_uri.toString()
```

Then I get a string from database and get a Uri from this code when I want to use the tree Uri next time:

```
tree_uri=Uri.parse(string);
```

But it's a Invalid URI when I use it. So what should I do make the tree_uri isn't invalid?

Comment: That should work. Your code looks ok.

Comment: I want the uri can still work when I restart the app.

Comment: That should work. Your code looks ok. Are you sure the saved and retrieved string are exactly the same? Put it in shared preferences too for a test.

Comment: I send the Uri to another Activity, it can still work. But if I send uri.tostring() to another Activity and get Uri from the string, it's a invalid.

Comment: That is hard to believe.

Comment: Do I need to add anything in androidmanifest.xml if I want to use takePersistableUriPermission?

Comment: No. Not needed al all.